# how make a query in sequelize with a OR condition when that field is the foreignkey

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i need some help with this query in sequelize, this query is working exactly how i want, but i don't have idea how can do that OR condition:

```
select * from 
core."Customers" c 

inner join core."Townhouses" t 
on t.id = c.townhouseid

inner join portal."TownhouseFreeFreights" tf 
on tf.townhouseid = t.id
or tf.townhouseid is null

where c.id = 1
and tf."minValue" >= 0
```

the problem for me is that part:
**or tf.townhouseid is null**

what i supposed to do here:

```
getFreightRules(){
    return Customer.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Townhouse,
        require: true,
        include:[{
          model: TownhouseFreeFreights,
        }]
      }]
    
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#examples-with--code-op-and--code--and--code-op-or--code-)

```
getFreightRules(){
    return Customer.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Townhouse,
        require: true,
        include:[{
          model: TownhouseFreeFreights,
          where: {
           [Op.or]: [
             { tf.townhouseid: t.id },
             { tf.townhouseid: null }
           ]
          }
        }]
      }]
    
    })
  }
```

alternatively

```
getFreightRules(){
    return Customer.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Townhouse,
        require: true,
        include:[{
          model: TownhouseFreeFreights,
          where: {
           tf.townhouseid: {
             [Op.or]: [t.id, null]
           }
         }
       }]
     }]
    })
  }
```

Comment: even when i already have a model relation between TownhouseFreeFreights and Townhouse? that Op.or will subscribe model relation?  
 static relations(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Townhouse , {foreignKey: 'townhouseid' })

  }

Comment: Yes, the model relation is necessary for you to have in order to include model TownhouseFreeFreights in Customer. Otherwise it wouldn't work. "where" is just a query parameter and if you need to have more than one "where" (as `WHERE` in SQL) you can pass an object with an array query objects or an object where you use Op.and, Op.or etc. for an array of values. This won't affect the relationship, it is just the sql query.